# How can I reconfigure my graphics tablet?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to re-configure my graphic tablet for Mac Pro 2013 running macOS El Capitan. The table includes the tablet with hotkeys and softkeys plus the pen that has two buttons.

In the configuration, there's an option to "Switch screens" for users with dual-monitors. The problem is that the "Switch Screen" options are only avaliable for the pen buttons and not the hotkeys/softkeys on the tablet. The pen is awkward, so it'll be way easier to switch screens by pressing one of the tablet buttons instead of scrunching my fingers and producing extra clicks.

What have I done? I tried modifying the .plist file by copying the pen button parameters to the hotkey section and overwriting the exisiting file.  No such yet.

See the images of the current settings.

[image: Pen buttons screen]

[image: Tablet hotkeys + softkeys screen --- "switch screens" is not an option in the drop-down menu and I want to add it]

**Here's the PLIST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Brand</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>ExpressKeys</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>6</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>10</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>11</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>11</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Key11</string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>11</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>24</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>4</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>27</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>5</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>6</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>33</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>7</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>49</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>8</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>48</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>9</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>Column</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>HotKeyDisable</key>
        <false/>
        <key>HotKeyNum</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>LeftHandMode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PenButtons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PenButton1</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>PenButton1Keyboard</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>11</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>PenButton2</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <key>PenButton2Keyboard</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Exist</key>
            <true/>
            <key>ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>PenMonitor</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationA</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationB</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationC</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationD</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationE</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationF</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorCarlibrationG</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PenMonitorExpressKey</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PressureSensitive</key>
    <integer>-3</integer>
    <key>ScreenSel</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>SoftKeys</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>11</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>10</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>40</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>11</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>37</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>12</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>46</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>13</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>14</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>31</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>15</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>35</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>4</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>5</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>6</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>7</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>8</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>34</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>9</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyCode</key>
            <integer>38</integer>
            <key>command</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>control</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>option</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>shift</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>SoftKeyEnable</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>SoftKeyNum</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>TabletMaxX</key>
    <integer>40000</integer>
    <key>TabletMaxY</key>
    <integer>25000</integer>
    <key>WorkAreaRatio</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Bottom</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Left</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Right</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
        <key>Top</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```